# Load time in dropdown and save it in mysql database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I want to load date and time in dropdown box.If current day is selected, time should start 2 hours from now. So far, I have loaded the date and time. One problem is that, when I select the next day, it not showing from start time. Also when I save the field to mysql database, it just saves first time alone. Suppose if the time selected is 18:00-19:00, It only saves 18. I have used varchar field.

So far my work are

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var hour = d.getHours()+2;
        $('#timeInterval option[value="'+hour+'"]').prop('selected', true);
    });
    $(".form-control[name=dtime]").change(function(){
       selDate = $(this).children(":selected").val();
       var d = new Date();
       var month = d.getMonth()+1;
       var day = d.getDate();
       var hour = d.getHours()+2;

       var curDate = (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '-' +
        (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
        d.getFullYear();


       // If selected date is equal to the current Date
        if(selDate != curDate){
            $('#timeInterval option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true); // Select 9:00 AM
        }else {
            $('#timeInterval option[value="'+hour+'"]').prop('selected', true); // Select the next 2 Hours
    });
</script>

<select class="form-control"  name="dtime" onchange="javascript:valueselect(this)" >
<option value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y') ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()) ;?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+86400) ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+86400) ;?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+172800) ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+172800) ;?></option>
</select>
<?php
    echo "<select name='dnotes' id='timeInterval'>";
    $now = new DateTime();
    $s1=$now->format('H')+2;
    $starttime='09:00';
    $endtime='23:00';
$start    = new DateTime($starttime);
$end      = new DateTime($endtime);
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H'); // Set the interval to One hour
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt)
{
    $dt2 = clone $dt;
    $dt2->add(new DateInterval('PT1H')); // Add One hour
    echo '<option type="time" value="'.$dt->format("G").'">'.$dt->format('H:i').' - '.$dt2->format('H:i').' </option><br />';
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value field of option tag has $dt->format("G")

Shouldn't it be $dt->format('H:i').' - '.$dt2->format('H:i') ?

Comment: echo '<option value="'.$dt->format('H:i').' - '.$dt2->format('H:i').'">'.$dt->format('H:i').' - '.$dt2->format('H:i').' </option>';

Comment: That worked.... It saved the values to db. One more question, when I select the next date, it is not showing from the start time

Comment: I'm sorry. I need to hide the previous time for today's date... Suppose, If it shows 19:00-20:00, then time starting from 9:00-10:00 to 18:00-19:00 should hide...

Comment: check datetime in for loop and add continue. if(date is current && if current time[hours] is less than current) then continue